# Vagrant SSH failed with ubuntu/xenial64

Tags: windows, vagrant

I have done `vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64; vagrant up --provider virtualbox`, then when I was trying to `vagrant ssh` I got message with folowing.

> no kex alg

Comment: most likely your ssh client is getting too old, can you run `ssh -V` to find out the version

Comment: @FrédéricHenri you should write down as answer~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely your ssh client is getting too old, can you run ssh -V to find out the version and upgrade if needed.